# AlphaVantage Search Symbol - Brazilian Tickers

Tags: programming

I'm trying to find in AlphaVantage Python API the following Brazilian Index, however i didn't find it.

IMAT (Materials Brazilian Index) UTIL (Utility Brazilian Index)

What i've tried the following:

```
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords=util&apikey=XXX
```

Additionally, is it possible to find tickers by region? I've tried the following without success:

```
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&region=Brazil&keywords=util&apikey=XXX
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Single stocks listed on exchanged have tickers. Are you sure your indices even have tickers?

Comment: Yes, I'm. In YahooFinance you can find it as follows:
UTIL.SA
IMAT.SA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two indices IMAT (Materials Brazilian Index) and UTIL (Utility Brazilian Index) are not available at alphavantage. You could use some ETF's instead that are listed on the NYSE:

```
 - EWZ  | iShares MSCI Brazil ETF
 - BRZU | Direxion Daily Brazil Bull 2X Shares
 - FLBR | Franklin FTSE Brazil ETF
 - EWZS | iShares MSCI Brazil Small-Cap ETF
 - BRF  | VanEck Vectors Brazil Small-Cap ETF
 - BZQ  | ProShares UltraShort MSCI Brazil
 - FBZ  | First Trust Brazil AlphaDEX Fund
 - UBR  | ProShares Ultra MSCI Brazil
```